# Saving Songs url path in Core Data app Crashes

Tags: ios, swift3

I am working an application in which songs are selected from the phone library and get the songs path. I get the songs path and want to save this songs path in Core Data, i got the songs path but when save this in Core Data App Crashes.  Please suggest a possible solution. Here is my Code.

```
@IBAction func selectMusic(_ sender: Any) { 


    mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .music)
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = true
    mediaPicker.delegate = self
    self.present(mediaPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let item: MPMediaItem? = (mediaItemCollection.items[0] as? MPMediaItem)

    print(item)

    let url: URL? = item?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as! URL?

    print("My Url : \(url)")

    var songsUrl : URL = url!

    let urlString = songsUrl.absoluteString

    songsUrlArray.append(urlString)

    print("SONGS ARRAY \(songsUrlArray)")

    audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
    audioPlayer.play()
 }
```

here is my save settings code

```
@IBAction func saveConfiguration(_ sender: Any) {

  //  let email = defaults.value(forKey: "userEmail")
    let email = "irfan@aol.com"

    let date = NSDate()
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    var dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)


    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Config_Table", into: context)

    let itemTwo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "PlayList_Table", into: context)

    newItem.setValue(email, forKey: "email")
    newItem.setValue(configurationnameTextField.text, forKey: "config_name")
    newItem.setValue(selectValueFromPickerView, forKey: "medi_type")
    newItem.setValue(sliderSelectedValue, forKey: "medi_duration")
    newItem.setValue(dateString, forKey: "medi_date")

    itemTwo.setValue(configurationnameTextField.text, forKey: "config_name")
    itemTwo.setValue(email, forKey: "email")
    itemTwo.setValue(songsUrlArray, forKey: "song_path")


    print(newItem)
    print(itemTwo)

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Saved")

    }
    catch{
        fatalError("Error")

    }

}
```

here is my core data structure where song_path save the URL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU6lO.png)

here is crash message report
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrFZm.png)

Comment: What is the crash message ? Have you added song_path key in CoreData after installing in Simualtor/Device ? If yes either install a fresh copy or increase model version number.

Comment: @NeverHopeless Please see the image description at the end of question, and i did not understand what you are saying.

Comment: The error is explicit. You set your song_path property to be a String, but when you create your entity, you put inside an Array. That's why it crashes.

Comment: Please suggest me a possible solution. In which way i store songs in array and then array is stored in Core Data.?

Comment: @NeverHopeless
var songsUrlArray = [String]() ...this array store url path selected from gallery.

Comment: From the array of song urls you have to pick the url of this particular song you are going to insert in DB. like : `itemTwo.setValue(songsUrlArray[0], forKey: "song_path")` where `0` refers first song url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
itemTwo.setValue(songsUrlArray, forKey: "song_path")
```

Your `song_path` must be an NSString. You are trying to save an Array.